# How to render image on Yaxis in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, renderer

I want to use `chart.renderer.image` to put a image on Yaxis. Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/F4qS8/)

Is there a easy way to put the image on Yaxis? For example I want to put the image on Yaxis [0,100]. It is very difficult to using the following way to do that.

```
chart.renderer.image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png', 0, 10, 30, 30)
    .add();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line:

```
 chart.renderer.image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png', 20, 50, 30, 30)
    .add();
```

first two parameters are responsible for position (x,y). So you should modify it to position object in yAxis, like in the example: http://jsfiddle.net/F4qS8/701/

Comment: Hey Sebastian, If I want to place this image on y-axis against the value how can I translate it to the plotting pixels? for example I want to place it near 10 and in reality 10 might be (100,23) How can I do that? SO that I can render the image there?

Comment: Found out we can use chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(Number value, [Boolean paneCoordinates]) **[http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels)** to get the y pixels for the "value" on the chart :) Thanks